# Why Piecewise() isn't being displayed properly by IPython.display.display()?

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, sympy

```
from IPython.display import display as mathPrint
from sympy import *

x = symbols("x")

mathPrint(Eq(abs(x), Piecewise((-x, x < 0), (0, x == 0), (x, x > 0)), evaluate=False))
```

It's printing the expression like this:
[image]

It isn't showing the 2nd condition of the function which should be **0 for x = 0**.

How can I get the desired output? Should I need to use any other display function?

Comment: It's not a display problem. It's something to do with `Piecewise`.  But you can use `(x, x >= 0)` to capture the `x==0` case.

Comment: While `x>0` returns a Relational, `x==0` is "explicitly" `False`.  `Piecewise` says such conditionals are omited.

Comment: hey @hpaulj, thanks so much. But one more query, suppose I need to define a function like this - 10 if x < 0, 20 if x == 0, 30 if  x > 0. Then how can I write it using Piecewise so that all 3 statements get displayed?

Comment: All I can do is read the docs, and try somethings. That's what my comment was based on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems. The first is that you are passing `evaluate=False` to `Eq` rather than to `Piecewise` (check the brackets carefully). The second problem is that you are passing th condition `x == 0` which simply evaluates to `False`. To make a symbolic representation of an equality you should use `Eq`. In that case `evaluate=False` is not even needed (in this example):

```
In [145]: Piecewise((-x, x < 0), (0, Eq(x, 0)), (x, x > 0))
Out[145]: 
⎧-x  for x < 0
⎪             
⎨0   for x = 0
⎪             
⎩x   for x > 0
```

Comment: And one more question, how can I add condition like this: -x for x <= 0, 10 for 0 < x < 10, 50 for x >= 10? I mean, how can I add the middle one?

Comment: You need `(0 < x) & (x < 10)`.

Comment: Hurray!! Thank you very much Oscar!